# HTML JavaScript - changing info in cell by ID

Tags: javascript, html-table

I've got this problem:
I have a table in HTML, that I want to edit via Javascript.
The table info is of rooms with either value 0 or 1.
I have two buttons that can change a cell, that can set the value to 1 or 0, but I want a function connected to one button, that changes the value, as 1 gets to 0, and 0 gets to 1.

One solution I find is to give each cell an ID and change it, and the other one is to use row/cell from the table.

```
<table id="table1">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">
        <tr>    
            <td> Room </td>
            <td> Status </td>   
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> r1 </td>
            <td id="room1"> 0 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> r2 </td>
            <td> 0 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> r3 </td>
            <td> 1 </td>
        </tr>
```

Currently I've tried:

```
<button type="button" onclick="metode1()">Room 1 => 0/1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="metode2()">Room 1 => 0</button>

    <script>
        function metode1(){         
            if(document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML > 0) {
                document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML = 0;
            } 
            else {
                document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML = 1;
            } 
        }

        function metode2(){
            document.getElementById("table1").rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML = 0;
        }  

    </script>
```

But neither of them work..
What can I do?

Comment: Re accepting and such: You're correct, you can only *accept* one answer. Separately, though, when you have rep >= 15, you'll be able to upvote useful questions and answers, [more here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`metode1` would work, but your initial text in the element has spaces on either side of the `0`, so `>` can't implicitly convert it to a number. If you remove the spaces (in the markup, or by doing `.innerHTML.trim()` on a modern browser), the implicit conversion from string to number will work. You might consider converting explicitly, but you'll still have to trim.

**Live Example** with the spaces removed in the markup:

```js
function metode1() {
  if (document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML > 0) {
    document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td>Room</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r1</td>
    <td id="room1">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="metode1()">Room 1 => 0/1</button>
```

**Live Example** using `trim`:

```js
function metode1() {
  if (document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML.trim() > 0) {
    document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td>Room</td>
    <td>Status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r1</td>
    <td id="room1"> 0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="metode1()">Room 1 => 0/1</button>
```

Note that `trim` was added in ECMAScript5 (2009) and so may not be on some older JavaScript engines. It's easily shimmed, though.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, finally!
Didnt know it was that sensetive. Thought spaces were auto-trimmed. Makes sence though..

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<button type="button" onclick="metode1()">Room 1 => 0/1</button>
function metode1(){         
            if(document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML.trim() =="1") {
                document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML = 0;
            } 
            else {
                document.getElementById("room1").innerHTML = 1;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Would work I think, but I ended up using T.Js answear :)